# How Plugin get directory Url of my Site

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

When we download a plugin , it auto added some files to our footer 
For-Example

```
<script type='text/javascript' 
src='example.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=5.0.1' >
</script>
```

as I talk contact form 7 Plugin . What I want to know in which file its pick my site directory path  'example.com/wp-content/' this thing

Please Help if you got my point!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I understand Nothing! What are you trying to do? As it is currently written, It is really hard to tell.

Comment: Want to change know that from where the plugin is getting the directory path
where is that code placed and in which file?

Comment: Look for a `wp_enqueue_script` in the Contact Form 7 plugin directory. That will tell you how the plugin is referencing the the js file - probably something like this `plugins_url( 'includes/js/scripts.js', __FILE__ )`

Answer (score 0):

It is probably pulling from the wp_options table of the database: look for the value siteurl in the option_name column

It could also come from the wp_config.php file or even the functions file.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your plugin name is 'my-plugin'.

So, inside your main file of your plugin write following code -

`plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )`

This will give you whole path, till your plugin folder. Here as per example -

```
example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/
```